# psycopg2 postgres sql request of sum and count returns format which is not respecting json.dump

Tags: json, postgresql, psycopg2, simplejson

I have the following query:

```
import psycopg2
import simplejson as json


payload = {
   "type": type,
   "creators": None,
   "type_count": None,
   "total_monitary_action_count": None
  }

cur.execute('''
      SELECT SUM(currentmonitaryactioncount) as totalmonitaryactioncount , COUNT(*) as totalnumberofcreators
      FROM users_contentcreatorusers
      WHERE approvedcreator = true AND ''' + str(type) + ''' = true
      ''')
```

then

```
 record = cur.fetchall()
 record = json.dumps(record)
 print('here is the record dump thing')
 print(record)
 payload["total_monitary_action_count"] = record[0]
 payload["type_count"] = record[1]
```

the print out

```
here is the record dump thing
[[102923243, 2043]]
```

here is the result of my

```
payload["total_monitary_action_count"] = record[0]
payload["type_count"] = record[1]
```

`'type_count': '[', 'total_monitary_action_count': '['}`

now i see the double []and i attempted `record[0][0]` with no positive effect.

What am I doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the result is a list with a list, you should retrieve the data as

```
payload["total_monitary_action_count"] = record[0][0]
payload["type_count"] = record[0][1]
```

and remove the following line which is going to serializes the result, that in this case I don't see why it is needed.

```
record = json.dumps(record)
```

Comment: well done this solved the problem. Thank you very much! A follow up question, how come I don't need to serialize?

Comment: [cursor.fetchall](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/cursor.html?highlight=fetchall#cursor.fetchall) is going to return a list with the rows of the query, so you can extract the result directly.